# What are the PowerShell built-in drives called and where do I find a list of them?

Tags: powershell

What are the PowerShell built-in drives called and where do I find a list of them?

When I say drives (because I don't know what they're really called), I'm refering to something like these as examples

```
dir function:
dir variable:
```

I am specifically looking for how to **dir** the list of local variables or global variables in a PowerShell session.

I have done this before but can't remember what the drive names were just now.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `Get-PSDrive`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the PowerShell built-in drives called and where do I find a
>   list of them?

To read more about providers, run `Get-Help about_Providers` in PowerShell or use online reference: [about_Providers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847791.aspx).

To get list of available providers use `Get-PSProvider`.

> I am specifically looking for how to dir the list of local variables
>   or global variables in a PowerShell session.

Use `Get-Variable`:

```
Get-Variable -Scope Local
Get-Variable -Scope Global
Get-Variable -Scope Script
```

Answer (score 0):

[`gdr`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849796.aspx)

For your second question: `get-childitem -path variable: | ft *`

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, I was looking for the way to do the following.

ls Variable:

rm Variable:

I realise that ls and rm are aliases for Get-ChildItem and Remove-Item respectively, but I find the aliases easier to remember.

Thanks for the help all.